# Dictionary of Objects

Tags: c#, collections, dictionary

I hava a dictionary of Objects of a class Columns

```
Dictionary<double, Columns>
```

Columns is a class of columns, i.e. name, post code, etc, mobile phone. I would like to make Columns class as much open for extension as possible, so it will be no trouble to add more classes. I need to set few of the columns to be there always, and would like the user to be able to define which columns to display from the remaining, and also add custom columns. Each columns has to have a method getValue()

My idea is to create an abstract class Column and derive specific columns from it. Make each child class implement the getValue() method by making it abstract what should force it to be overriden (am I correct?). 
I will define enum which will list all available column types.
Finally, a class Columns would keep all the available columns in dictionary

```
Dictionary<enum, Column>
```

My question is: is my thinking process correct? 
Is there any room for improvement? 
Would it be a better idea to use interfaces? 
Finally, is this design going to be efficient and fast for rapidly changing values in columns, i.e. within a second I might have to update 50 different records in this dictionary.

Programming language: c#

Thank you in advance for any input.

Comment: post it here http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: An advice regarding your implied question about efficiency and performance: Don't get lost in [micro-optimization](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/01/the-sad-tragedy-of-micro-optimization-theater.html).

Answer (score 0):

This approach is not very good, because you could only have one column of every value in the `enum`.

Maybe you should elaborate a bit more on why you want to use a `Dictionary` and what the key for the `Dictionary` should be.

Comment: The key for the first dictionary is ID which is set at the initialization. I need to be able to quickly get to whichever ID I need at the moment.

Comment: you could only have one column of every value in the enum - I need only unique columns.

Comment: Any reason for not using data sets with LINQ? Why the implementation overhead?

Comment: I was not aware of DataSet but it actually might be an interesting idea. I will look into it.